# How to get access to layers without geometry?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a QGIS project with some layers without geometry. 
I develop a QGIS plugin. I want to get all my layers by:

```
iface.mapCanvas().layers()
```

but I get only layers with geometry. How I can get layers without geometry?

My no-geometry layers are just tables in a database. I could connect to the database in order to access data but I would like to know whether it is possible to access them as QGIS layers (in analogous way to QgsVectorLayers).

Comment: You don't say what version of QGIS you are using, but the method you describe works for PostGIS data at both QGIS 1.8 and the latest development version.

Comment: @gsherman I use QGIS 1.8 but I can't get no-geometry layers from `iface.mapCanvas().layers()`. How I can get them without connecting directly to a database?

Comment: @tomto try to post somewhere one of these "layers" without geometry to download (I never see one...), I would like to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `iface.mapCanvas().layers()`.

Use `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()` instead.

`QgsMapLayerRegistry` contains all layers from current QGIS project - also layers without geometry.